# Draw Lines Diagonally in a particular NSTableview cell

Tags: cocoa, nstableviewcell

Is there a way to draw lines diagonally in NSTableview cell.Can u please post sample to do this.I am new to the Mac development.Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, easily.

You need to create a **subclass** of `NSTextFieldCell` which is actually the type of cell a `NSTableView` uses to display text.

Subclassing an class creates a new version of that class that does all that the original class did plus more.

This is using Xcode 4. If you are using Xcode 3 let me know.

In Xcode, create a new file by choosing ***File > New > New File...***

[image: New File]

In the sheet that pops up choose ***Objective-C Class*** and hit ***Next***.

[image: Objc class]

Make it a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`, which is what we will be making a modified copy of. Hit ***Next***.

[image: subclass]

You can save it as anything you want, but for the purposes of this tutorial, save it as *MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell*. Hit ***Save***.

[image: saving]

Two new files should pop up.

[image: files]

Click on the *.m* file. This is the implementation file that tells what the methods in the class do.
Its contents should be similar to below:

```
//
//  MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell.m
//  CustomCell
//
//  Created by spudwaffle on 7/4/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell.h"

@implementation MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Below the `init` method add a `drawInteriorWithFrame: inView:` method.
The application calls the `drawInteriorWithFrame: inView:` method each time the cell needs to render on screen.

Your code should now look like this:

```
@implementation MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

}

@end
```

The first thing you need to do is just draw a standard `NSTextFieldCell`.
This can be done by calling:

```
[super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
```

This draws a normal `NSTextFieldCell` in the exact area the program wants it to.

Now, we need to draw our custom lines. Let's put them 5 pixels apart and make them 1 pixel wide.
This calls for a `for` loop!

```
for (int i = 0; i < cellFrame.size.width/5; i ++) {

}
```

This makes a `int` that equals `0`,adds to that count every time the loop runs, and stops when `i` reaches the amount of lines that need to be drawn.

Next, put in the drawing code to draw the lines.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cellFrame.size.width/5; i ++) {
        NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(i * 5, cellFrame.origin.y)];
        [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint((i * 5) + 2, cellFrame.origin.y + cellFrame.size.height)];
        [[NSColor grayColor]set];
        [path setLineWidth:1];
        [path stroke];
}
```

This:

1. Creates an `NSBezierPath`, which is used to draw lines and shapes.
2. Moves the start of the path to the bottom edge of the cell.
3. Draws a line to the top edge of the cell.
4. Sets the drawing color to gray.
5. Sets the drawing line width to `1`.
6. Draws the line.

It does this over and over for each line thanks to the `for` loop.

Here is the completed `MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell.m` file. You don't need to worry about the `.h` one for now.

```
#import "MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell.h"

@implementation MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    for (int i = 0; i < cellFrame.size.width/5; i ++) {
        NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(i * 5, cellFrame.origin.y)];
        [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint((i * 5) + 2, cellFrame.origin.y + cellFrame.size.height)];
        [[NSColor grayColor]set];
        [path setLineWidth:1];
        [path stroke];
    }
}

@end
```

Now, we need to set the cells in the table view to use this class.

Click on your `MainMenu.xib` file.
Click on the cell in a row of your table view until it turns blue.

[image: blue cell]

Then, hit the button in the right side bar that looks like so:
[image: button]

Change the ***Class*** to `MyDiagonalLinedTextFieldCell` and hit enter.

[image: class change]

Now hit run and enjoy the fruits of your labor!

[image: custom cell window]

Mess with the drawing code until you get the exact kind of lines you want.

Feel free to contact me with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a beautiful answer, and very well presented. Still, I tried it, and it seems to be incomplete or inaccurate. I have 4 columns in my NSTableView, and apply the custom cell to just the right one - for some reason only the FIRST (left) column gets the special diagonals drawn, no matter what I do.

It seems that the logic in your drawing code is missing some step of "aligning to the positional column" which I really don't know how to do.

you could also improve the sample by only introducing the custom cell .m once - and adding the .h to accompany it - thus demonstrating the inheritance.